# Difference running script in Canopy vs Command Line

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canopy

I have a script that outputs a series of images to a Notebook, which I have simplified below:

```
import os
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

path = sys.path[0]
os.chdir(path)

def on_close():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1250x550')

n = ttk.Notebook(root)
n.grid()

imgs = [img for img in os.listdir(path) if img.endswith('.png')]

for img in imgs:
    f = ttk.Frame(n)
    n.add(f, text=img)
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=img)
    label = ttk.Label(f, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=(300,0))

root.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_close)
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the script from the command line in Windows, the script works as is.  If I change my code to  `root = tk.Toplevel()`, an extra window appears (ie. the implicit tk.Tk() window), which is what I expected.

However, when I run the above script from within Canopy, I get an error saying "pyimage doesn't exist".  I can resolve this by changing my code to `root = tk.Toplevel()`, and everything runs normally with no extra window.

Why is there a discrepancy when I run from Canopy?  I've read questions where people needed to change `root = tk.Toplevel()` when displaying images because they were somehow creating two root windows within their script. However, I don't believe that describes my situation, and doesn't explain why my script works from the command line but not Canopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Canopy's (IPython) kernels are created in PyLab mode with a default Qt backend. For information about switching / disabling this, see https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469880-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-or-Pyglet-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel